# Auto populate HTML Select box with years past and future

Tags: php

Whats the best way to auto populate a select box in a form with years in PHP.

I want to be able to do 15 years in the past from the current year and 5 years in the future from the current year.

i have looked around online and can only find where they populate for x amount of years

Comment: If you have example code and know how to add/subtract, this is trivial.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: `$years = range( (date("Y")-15) ,  (date("Y")+5) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$currentValue = 2008;
$past = 15;
$future = 5;
if ($currentValue && ($currentValue < date('Y') - $past || $currentValue > date('Y') + $future)) {
    echo "<option value=\"$currentValue\" selected=\"selected\">$currentValue</option>\n";
}
for ($year = date('Y') - $past; $year <= date('Y') + $future; $year++) {
    if ($year == $currentValue) {
        echo "<option value=\"$year\" selected=\"selected\">$year</option>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<option value=\"$year\">$year</option>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect - thanks. how about if there is a value in the database (for when i edit the record) how can i make it automatically select the value in the database?

Comment: your edit works great. thanks. just a thought, if the current value is 1994 then it wont show as it is only going to go back as far as 1998. how can i make it display just 1994 rather than the select box?